# Does target directory contain sensitive information?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I was setting up my first Rust program and pushing the changes to github. I committed the target directory that was created when I made my rust program with Cargo. Does this file contain sensitive information?

Comment: At the very least, it contains full path to your program on your computer which may leak your local username.

Comment: You should not commit it anyway. It is a big blob of generated binary data, that is the worst thing for git. I think it may contain sensitive info, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But doesn't Cargo already generate a .gitignore file?

Comment: I already pushed the changes but I guess Its a learning lesson. I was following the Rust documentation and I hadn't read about any warnings but wanted to track my progress with Rust.

Comment: I read somewhere else, I needed to use cargo init or some other command, it hadnt generated a gitignore for me unfortunately

Comment: Both `cargo new` and `cargo init` generate a .gitignore file, I checked now.

Comment: I used cargo new to initially create my project, no gitignore was generated, addtionally, when I try "cargo init" I get this in console: `cargo init` cannot be run on existing Cargo packages

Comment: I got `cargo init directoryName` to work, although, again the gitignore file was not generated

Comment: `cargo new` and `cargo init` should generate a `.gitignore` _depending on the `--vcs` option._ This option defaults to `git` unless you are already in a (subdirectory of a) Git repo, in which case it defaults to `none`. This can be [configured](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#cargo-newvcs).

Answer (score -1):

It contains build output which means the final executable file plus a bunch of intermediate files the compiler produces when compiling